# extracting key value pair

Tags: c#, .net, regex, arrays, json

I am working on Rest api. It is working fine. When i request it, it sends me a response. Actually this response is an array consisting of sub array and further key:value pairs in them. Now i want to extract these key:value pairs in C#. I thought of regex to extract substring but i have no knowledge of regex yet. but i tried to first get the sub array like.

Input string is

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "kashif",
    "father_name": "mirza",
    "contact": "21321",
    "email": "sdf",
    "image": "sdfsdf"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Kashif",
    "father_name": "Mirza",
    "contact": "0342809211",
    "email": "shadbagh@wele.com",
    "image": "photo[1].jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Abdussadiq",
    "father_name": "Abdul Haq Khan",
    "contact": "03449066113",
    "email": "abdus.sadiq04@gmail.com",
    "image": "1393602_698558840157121_1872079026_n.jpg"
  }
]
```

C# code for regex

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\{)(.*)(?=\})",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
    {

        foreach(var matchgroup in match.Groups)
            Console.WriteLine(matchgroup);
    }
```

It returns me the result but not according to my needs. It returns me like

```
    "id": "1",
    "name": "kashif",
    "father_name": "mirza",
    "contact": "21321",
    "email": "sdf",
    "image": "sdfsdf"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Kashif",
    "father_name": "Mirza",
    "contact": "0342809211",
    "email": "shadbagh@wele.com",
    "image": "photo[1].jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Abdussadiq",
    "father_name": "Abdul Haq Khan",
    "contact": "03449066113",
    "email": "abdus.sadiq04@gmail.com",
    "image": "1393602_698558840157121_1872079026_n.jpg"
```

So that means it is removing the the just outer brackets but not the inner ones.

So my questions are:

1. What i am doing wrong in above code?
2. If i have to get key:value pair then what else i need to do?

Comment: Its a `JSON`. Isn't there any `JSON` parsing library in `C#`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use `regex` for that.
The data you're trying to parse are in `JSON` format.

For example, you could parse it with Json.NET

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> MyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(JsonData);
```

If you want a native support, try [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (it also gives you an example of how to parse it directly into classes, which is better than dictionary regarding on your JSON data structure)

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> MyData = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(JsonData);
```

Comment: Don't know very detail in about `C#`. Is it a builtin library? or a third party library like `Newtonsoft`(not sure the exact name)?

Answer (score 2):

You are using greedy regex `.*` that's why you are getting all. Instead use non-greed `.*?` have then in pieces.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

After that, if you need to parse more, then use regex on the captured group(`matchgroup`):

```
(".*?(?<!\\)":".*?(?<!\\)")    <-- you'll get spoofed here if single quote, or no quotes
```

**But still**, I'll always **suggest you** to use any `json` parsing library for this.

Answer (score 1):

using regexp for this kind of task is a bad practice Use Json.NET library

Answer (score 1):

First you can create a class like this:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Father_Name { get; set; }
       public string Contact { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       //Could be byte[]
       public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

And then you can use the JavaScriptSerializer class like below:

```
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<MyClass> myClassCollection = serializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(result);
    //Where result is your json string
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns data in `JSON` format, you should either use .NET's built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` class under `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace or third party library such as `Json.NET` for reading this response.

To use `JavaScriptSerializer`, first you'll need to add `System.Web.Extensions` reference using `Add Reference...`

Using `Regex` to parse `JSON` is a bad practice.